# How can I convert these escape sequences back to their original characters?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

**JsonNode.Parse()** seems to convert my `<` and `>` to the escape sequences `\u003C` and `\u003E` when they appear inside double-quotes `""`.

How can I convert these escape sequences back to their original characters?

This is my C# code:

```
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
Console.WriteLine("JsonNode test");
var testString = "{ \"testString\" : \"<...>\" }";
Console.WriteLine($"{testString}, {testString.Length}");
var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(testString);
var jsonString = jsonNode.ToJsonString();
Console.WriteLine($"{jsonString}, {jsonString.Length}");
```

Output:

```
JsonNode test
{ "testString" : "<...>" }, 26
{"testString":"\u003C...\u003E"}, 32
```

I've tried the HtmlDecode and UrlDecode methods, but they are not right for this situation.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The result is valid JSON which will deserialize just fine.

Comment: You are correct sir!  It does work just fine with the escaped characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json is still valid, but I usually always recommend to use Neftonsoft.Json since it has much much less problems, but you can use a string Replace as well

```
var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(testString);
var jsonString = jsonNode.ToJsonString().Replace("\\u003C","<").Replace("\\u003E",">");
```

result

```
{"testString":"<...>"}
```

another option is to use UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping, but it is not safe in some cases

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
        WriteIndented = true
    };
var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonNode, options);
```

Comment: The UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping setting works great!  Thank you!